# How can I unsubscribe myself from Ingress notification list?

Tags: ingress

I've searched far and wide, including their help, and their dashboard and their intel map, and found nothing.

Is there a way to make Ingress not send me notifications on resonators of mine that were destroyed etc? I'm afraid that my mail is compromised and I don't want sensitive data there. (Also, it's annoying to get a notification every time something happens).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the Ingress app, go to Ops, then Device, and the option you want is "Email Notifications". Hit "Toggle" until it reads "off".

Answer (score 1):

in the new scanner version (30th of October 2018) it's under `Settings` and then scroll down to "Email" section and uncheck "Game notifications (Portal under attach, etc."